# React native ios error, 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled

Tags: react-native

Trying to build my react native app I get this error:

error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /xxxxr/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Switch/Switch.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled (103:41):

I have added:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

To my `.babelrc` but I still get the error. How can I build my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` plugin as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

Try adding below code to your .babelrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

Hope it will help you.